# Sharing Adobe Flash Projector (.EXE) over Local Area Network

Tags: networking, flash, exe, sharing

A forthcoming project requires that a Flash projector (.exe) be kept on a server and accessed by multiple users over network (LAN). There will be a central access database as a back-end. I am using a third party SWF2EXE (SWF Studio) product to have database functionality. I would like to know if sharing an .exe file this way is practical. I know it's not a typical client-server methodology but I can't use Server side platform like ASP due to lack of resources at the client's place. Is it likely to cause any crashes if the same .exe is launched simultaneously by network users doing a simultaneous read/write to database (mdb)?

Answer (score 0):

Each computer should get a copy of the exe file, and it should be only the database which is shared.  If you are on a LAN and you are using MS Access, placing the MDB file in a shared location should be fine.

You may also want to check what the concurrent user limit is for an ms access database.

Andrew